# How to set selected properties in multiple checkboxes with foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

I want to display all the category and I want to set selected properties to multiple Checkboxes.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<?php 

$allCategories = $category->getAllCategory();

if ($allCategories) {

$categoryAccess = $category_permitted->getCategoriesByUserId($user_info[0]->id);

foreach ($allCategories as $key => $items) {
    if ($categoryAccess) {
        foreach ($categoryAccess as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_access[]" value=" <?php echo $items->id ?> " <?php echo (isset($categoryAccess) && @$categoryAccess[$key]->id == $items->id) ? 'checked' : '' ?>><?php echo $items->title?>
            <?php
        }
    }

    ?>

    <?php
}
}
 ?>
    </div>
```

After looping through `$categoryAccess` I got two options selected but I am getting all category repeating twice as an output i.e category1 category 1 category 2 category 2 category 3 category 3 category 4 category 4.

I have 4 categories which have checkboxes and for the output, 2 of the categories should be checked. I am getting error in `<?php echo (isset($categoryAccess) && $categoryAccess->id == $items->id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>` it gives this error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object and when I do `<?php echo (isset($categoryAccess) && $categoryAccess[0]->id == $items->id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>` it gives data but of 0 index only.

`var_dump($categoryAccess)` :

```
array(2)
{
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3)
    {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["title"]=> string(25) "category1"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#20 (3)
    {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["title"]=> string(18) "category2"
    }
}
```

Comment: result of `var_dump($categoryAccess);` please

Comment: Make a var_dump of $categoryAccess to see what you are actually dealing with there.

Comment: `$categoryAccess` is an array, you can't access its properties by using the object operator `->`. you should loop over the `$categoryAccess` to access its objects

Comment: In addition to your error, you should really be calling `getCategoriesByUserId()` outside of the loop, not inside of it, since it isn't dependent upon `$items`.  No reason to waste resources/time calling it every time when you're just going to get the same result each time.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have corrected my code.

Comment: @Alisha In the body of your question, you say "3 of the categories should be checked".  But you are only getting two rows from `$categoryAccess`.  Something isn't adding up.

Comment: @Mohammad I have looped `$categoryAccess` as you told me to do but I am receiving another error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$allCategories = $category->getAllCategory();
$categoryAccess = $category_permitted->getCategoriesByUserId($user_info[0]->id);

foreach ($allCategories as $items) {

  $checked = '';    

  foreach ($categoryAccess as $value) {

    if($items->id == $value->id){
      $checked = 'checked';
      break;
    } 
  }
  ?>

  <input type="checkbox" name="cat_access[]" value="<?php echo $items->id ?>" <?php echo $checked ?>>
  <?php echo $items->title?>

  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting two errors after using the code shared by you which are Undefined offset: 3 and Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.

Comment: David : `$categoryAccess[$key]` Are you **sure** that `$categoryAccess` has `$key` as index ?

Comment: @Cid $categoryAccess has the $key as an index, when I do print_r($categoryAccess) it gives an array with two indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: @Alisha how much items in `$allCategories` ?

Comment: @Cid There are 4 items in $allCategories.

Comment: @Alisha then `$key` can be `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`

Comment: @Cid That's what davidloper answered before but that gave an error.

Comment: @Alisha can you try put a @ in front of the variable of $categoryAccess like this @$categoryAccess[$key]->id, the @ symbol will suppresses error messages and return null

Comment: @davidloper Yes it suppressed the error but that didn't give the expected output or two boxes checked.

Comment: @Cid I have modified the code, can you please have a look at it?

Comment: @Alisha I just changed my answer, it should now!

Comment: @davidloper the code you have shared gives an unexpected end of the file.

Comment: @Alisha Did you get the answer?

Comment: @davidloper Yes, I got the answer with updated code which was similar to yours and it helped.